# RealmSwift Generic Field

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this model:

```
 import Foundation
 import RealmSwift

 class Event: Object {

     dynamic var id              = 0
     dynamic var start_date      = NSDate()
     dynamic var end_date        = NSDate()
     dynamic var owner_id        = 0
     dynamic var subject         = ""
}
```

I would like to add a field like this:

```
 dynamic var detail:Object?
```

and then set this field with another model between (person, meeting, etc...) but it does not work, so than I tried to do this:

```
 class A : Object{
}

 class B:A{

}

 class C:A{

}
```

and the field is:

```
 dynamic var detail:A?
```

but if I set:

`event.detail = C` or `event.detail = B` I obtain no error but in the record I have an **empty array**, how can I fix this?

Comment: did you try using AnyObject instead of Object ?

Comment: no... i try!  thanks!

Comment: @VladLego RealmSwift doesn't accept `AnyObject` as a member variable.

Comment: If I were you, I would define to variables `let person: Person?` and `let meeting: Meeting?` instead of details.

Answer (score 1):

Due to Realm's architectural design, it's not possible to define a generic `Object` property that is capable of accepting multiple class types; a single class type must be explicitly defined for that property. For more information on Realm's capabilities in that regard, please check out the ['Model Inheritance' section](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#model-inheritance) of Realm's documentation.

I would encourage you to take a step back and reconsider your design to come up with an alternative design pattern for what you're attempting to achieve.

Ismail's suggestion of having multiple properties for each type of detail your `Event` object might require is a good idea. Alternatively, you could also bundle all of the properties of your `A`, `B`, and `C` subclasses into one `Detail` object, and simply only set the properties pertaining to that specific `Event` object.

Comment: Hmmm. Step back and don't use generics (or even inheritance) because Realm fails at generics. Maybe reconsider using Realm.

Comment: Thanks for the input nearly 6 years later Dave! 

Comment: You're welcome. Was there an expiry date on your advice?

Comment: No worries! I suppose my advice expires whenever this issue is closed I guess. https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3635 In any case, I left Realm in 2017, so if you have any feedback for the team, please follow up with them in their GitHub repo issues. :)